# Can Facebook Audiance Network Ads being displayed works without Facebook app installed?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-audience-network

In my iOS app I have integrated with Facebook Audiance Newtwork Ads , the Ads been shown correctly only if Facebook App installed .
But my target is to display the facebook Ads without enforcing users to install the Facebook application
Is this possible ?
How to workaround this ?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook tries to match the user's IDFA with his/her Facebook account. Therefore, the app must be installed on that same device and the user be logged in recently to make sure that this user has that IDFA.

> How are ads targeted to my app?
>
> When a user opens an app from one of our developer partners, we match it to a Facebook user using a unique identifier that we fetch from the device. None of the data that we get from the request is added to that user's Facebook profile.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/faq#a4

Comment: I have found that it's not necessary to have application installed , by showing weblogin for Facebook from within my application , so the IDFA will be available without the Native FB app

Comment: Audience Network is advertised to be used without implementing Facebook Login.  Asking the user to log into Facebook to receive ads may not be a good practice.